# Javascript recursive function returns undefined

Tags: javascript

I have this weird problem which makes no sense to me. What do I miss?

```
class AreaManager
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.areas = [];
        this.areas.push(new Area('Area1', this));
        this.areas[0].areas.push(new Area('AreaABC', this.areas[0]));
        this.areas[0].areas[0].areas.push(new Area('AreaABC123', this.areas[0].areas[0]));
        this.areas[0].areas.push(new Area('AreaDEF', this.areas[0]));
    }

    findAreaById(id, areas)
    {
        areas.forEach(a => {
            if(a.id == id)
                return a; //console.log()  prints the right Area object here
            else
                return this.findAreaById(id, a.areas);
        });
    }
}
class Area
{
    constructor(id, parent)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.areas = [];
    }
}


var _Manager;

function InitManager()
{
    _Manager = new AreaManager();
}

function GetSomeArea()
{
    var searchID = 'AreaDEF';
    var areaObject = _Manager.findAreaById(searchID);
    console.log(areaObject); //this is always undefined
}
```

I'm not sure what's the problem here. Even if I try to return a simple string or a number in the `if(a.id == id)` I get undefined.

Hope someone can explain this. Thank you

Comment: You're `return`ing from within the function passed to the `forEach()`, not from your main function

Comment: So what do i have to do? i'm used to c#.
Return the foreach?

Comment: Also you're not passing any `areas`, so I'd expect `TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`areas.forEach(a => {` return fron the `lambda function`. it is not returning from parent function. Use basic for loop to break loop.

For more info, you can read my blog: [how-to-break-the-loop-in-javascript](https://medium.com/@deepak_v/weird-part-how-to-break-the-loop-in-javascript-8bba3e658267)

```js
class AreaManager {
  constructor() {
    this.areas = [];
    this.areas.push(new Area("Area1", this));
    this.areas[0].areas.push(new Area("AreaABC", this.areas[0]));
    this.areas[0].areas[0].areas.push(
      new Area("AreaABC123", this.areas[0].areas[0])
    );
    this.areas[0].areas.push(new Area("AreaDEF", this.areas[0]));
  }

  findAreaById(id, areas = this.areas) {
    let merged = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < areas.length; i++) {
      if (areas[i].id == id) return areas[i];
      merged = merged.concat(areas[i].areas);
    }
    return this.findAreaById(id, merged);
  }
}
class Area {
  constructor(id, parent) {
    this.id = id;
    this.areas = [];
  }
}

var _Manager;

function InitManager() {
  _Manager = new AreaManager();
}

function GetSomeArea() {
  var searchID = "AreaDEF";
  var areaObject = _Manager.findAreaById(searchID);
  console.log(areaObject); //this is always undefined
}
InitManager();
GetSomeArea();
```

Comment: I'm still not getting it. Okay foreach can't be breaked. I updated my function to this:

`

    findAreaById(id, areas)
    {
        for (let i = 0; i < areas.length; i++) 
        {
            console.log(areas[i].id + " == " + id);
            
            if(areas[i].id == id)
                return areas[i]; 
            else
                return this.findAreaById(id, areas[i].areas);
        }
    }

`

But now he break the recursion without looking at all elements
Console.log() gives this:
Area1 == AreaDEF 
AreaABC == AreaDEF 
AreaABC123 == AreaDEF

Comment: i found bug in code. :-D so messy!!

Comment: There was one data, you have 2 array element. Once you have 2 arrays, and u return from first one. So it will never go for second. so u have to merge all and look into it. Simple.

Comment: Thanks, Sorry that i don't know Javascript functionalty. @Mods: thanks for closing my question and refer to a other problem which didn't helped at all.